# reinstall windows 8 on clean ubuntu hard drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

For a moth ago, I took a clean install of Ubuntu 13.10, I formated the entire hard drive that contained windows 8 and installed Ubuntu. Now I want to reinstall windows 8, but when I boot up with a bootable USB, my computer wont recognize the bootable USB unless its a bootable Linux usb... I have done a little bit research and I think it have something with MBR to do, but I have no idea what to do!

Please help :)

Comment: Was system pre-installed with Windows 8? And do you still have gpt partitioning? Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI, where Ubuntu can boot from gpt with UEFI or BIOS. And both only boot from MBR(msdos) partitioning with BIOS mode. Best to see current partitioning. sudo fdisk -lu (if BIOS) or sudo parted -l for either UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: the system was indeed pre-installed with windows 8



i cant find the bootable USB containing windows, so i cant install windows at all, and it makes boot into ubuntu, ive tried to format the entire hard drive and boot with a bootable windows usb, but the the system wont find the bootable usb, unless its a linux usb. 

What can i do, and how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

`WinUSB` application will helps you to create Bootable windows USB from ubuntu.

- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,run the below command to install winusb,

  ```
  sudo apt-get install winusb
  ```
- open winusb application,select the corresponding windows iso file.
- Then select the `target usb` option and click on install.

You had created a bootable windows usb from ubuntu.Then change the boot-order in bios to USB and install windows.

Comment: Ive done that, both in windows, ubuntu and OSX, the bootable usb has been formated in both FAT32 and NTFS and it still wont show... :/ thak you soo much for your answare anyway :)

Comment: In windows try `eze bootable usb` software to create bootable windows usb.Did you change boot order in bios.

Comment: Yes, and i dont have a windows system on my ubunut pc, its 100% ubunut, it wont find a bootable usb unless its a linuxs bootable usb

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an NTFS formatted partition to install Windows on and that one I believe has to be the first partition on the disk.

Comment: I do have a NTFS partition on my hard drive

Comment: By boot selection do you mean Bios? If you can't find it there it needs to be re-formatted.

Answer (score 0):

make the USB bootable. when you boot your system click <kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> to access the BIOS and select the USB to boot

Comment: I have made the USB bootable, but i cant find it in boot selection, but i find it on other computers

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a efi boot image for windows (there should be an EFI folder)

Make a 1 GB FAT32 partition on the HDD.

copy your windows install there.

boot from HDD.